Listening to selection changes, including clearing
I want to get my listeners notified if JTree's selection is cleared, not only when a new selection is successfully made.
The reason for that is my listeners refill associated GUI tables, and when the selection is cleared such tables must be cleared too — as opposed to retaining its previous state.
Can I achieve that with Swing's OOB functionality? This snippet casts doubt. At least, calling setSelectionInterval(..) is apparently not the way to go
// javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel#setSelectionInterval
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        // if selection cleared, an event is not fired
        if (index0 == -1 || index1 == -1) {
            return;
        }

        if (getSelectionMode() == SINGLE_SELECTION) {
            index0 = index1;
        }

        updateLeadAnchorIndices(index0, index1);

        int clearMin = minIndex;
        int clearMax = maxIndex;
        int setMin = Math.min(index0, index1);
        int setMax = Math.max(index0, index1);
        changeSelection(clearMin, clearMax, setMin, setMax);
    }


You might get more responses if you edit your question to include a [mre] that we can copy into our IDE, compile, run, and test.  A JFrame and JPanel with a JTree showing the undesired behavior would be sufficient.

Does this not help? How to Write a Tree Selection Listener

Took me less than a minute to make an example proving that clearing the selection generates an event. Why are you constructing a non-existent problem and how does staring at a method that indeed does not clear the selection help?
